# Why the facebook login in ios app only works for the creator of FB application？

Tags: facebook

I have created one FB application with the None type. And i have set the FB application to live already.

I added the FB login in application, and only used these privileges: public_profile, email.

With these settings, the FB login in my ios app only works for me, not all FB users. But the login function works well in my android app and web site.

So what can i do now ? Expect your useful help.